# How to use JSON to write a map file

Tags: java, json, libgdx

Hello I'm working on a 2d game with libgdx. Now I need a way to save vertices from a editor I am working on. I tought that all will be saved in JSON.

```
{
meshes: {
    atributes: {"POSITION", "COLOR"}
    vertices: [
    6.4, 5,4, 0.5, 0,3, 0.7, 1.0,
    ...
    ],
    part: {
       id: "part1",
       type: "TRIANGLES",
       indices: [
       0, 4, 3, 4, 0, 3, 2, 1, 0,
       ...
       ]
    }
}
}
```

This format is from libgdx g3d (g3dj file)

I'm new to JSON and I know i could do classes (Mesh, MeshParts... etc.) to save this values.

1. What would be a good way to write to json so I can delete and add vertives/parts
2. How to make a newline for example vertices: should only do POSITON and COLOR to one line. Or parts only 12 values per line (4 triangles)

Answer (score 0):

I personally like [google-gson](https://github.com/google/gson). You could use the [toJson](https://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/Gson.html#toJson(java.lang.Object)) function to easily store objects to json

For instance a map structure:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();   
Map<Object, Object> map= new HashMap<Object, Object>();
gson.toJson(map).toString();
```

Comment: libGdx has a class to work with json. I would more likely know how to make rules that json make a newline in a array of values.